# Is Iodoform test restricted for only methyl ketones?

Tags: organic-chemistry, identification

Do only methyl ketones give iodoform test? Where can a keto methyl group be present in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All compounds with $CH_3CO- $ or $CH_3CH(OH)-$ group answer iodoform test.